# Do strongly equivalent metrics have same isometry groups?

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

In my lecture notes on differential geometry I stumbled upon the following statement regarding the euclidean metric $d$ restricted to the unit sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ and the angle-distance $d_S$ on $\mathbb S^{n-1}$.

> The metrics $d$ and $d_S$ are equivalent, not just in the weak sense of inducing the same topology, but in the strong sense that the isometries of $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ are the same with respect to either metric, since the two metrics are simply monotonic functions of one another.

My question is whether it is true in general that if two metrics $d,d'$ on a set $X$ satisfy $cd\leq d'\leq Cd$ for some $C\geq c>0$, then the isometry groups $\operatorname{Isom}_d(X)$ and $\operatorname{Isom}_{d'}(X)$ coincide?

---

Here is my incomplete attempt at proving this. For sake of reducing unneeded parentheses, I'm gonna write $fx:=f(x)$ for maps $f\colon X\to X$ and $x\in X$.

Let $f\in\operatorname{Isom}_{d'}(X)$, i.e. $d'(fx,fy)=d'(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$. It immediately follows that
$$c\max\{d(x,y),d(fx,fy)\}\leq\underbrace{d'(fx,fy)}_{=d'(x,y)}\leq C\min\{d(x,y),d(fx,fy)\}.$$
We can distinguish two cases: $d(x,y)\leq d(fx,fy)$ or $d(fx,fy)\leq d(x,y)$. In the former case the previous inequality reduces to $cd(fx,fy)\leq Cd(x,y)$, which does not help all that much, because $C/c\geq1$. The latter case is no help either, and it does not look like I can get more out of those inequalities.

Do you have any idea how to prove this claim (if it is true in the first place)?

Comment: It is very false. For example the $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are Lipschitz equivalent but very far from having the same isometry group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay, I can see how a rotation by π/4 is an isometry in ℓ2, but not in ℓ1. Then, I don't understand the statement in my lecture notes. Thank you for your example :)

Comment: Well, Lipschitz equivalence doesn’t imply that the two metrics are monotonic functions of each other! It is in fact true that if two metrics are (strictly) monotonic functions of each other then their isometry groups agree - the point is that this implies that the set of spheres of various radii are the same (just with different labels).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ohh, your first sentence just made me realize that I thought about Lipschitz-equivalence and "being monotonic functions of each other" as being the same thing... I didn't realize that "monotonic" was referring to the $\arcsin$ in $d_S=2\arcsin\circ\frac d2$. Well, that just shows I shouldn't do maths when I'm absolutely tired. Thank you very much :)